# What is the 'bs' option in dd?

Tags: dd

I've found conflicting information on the internet on whether the `bs` in a command like `dd bs=512 if=/home/Downloads/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb` stands for "bytes per second" or "block size". I couldn't find anything in the man pages, as the only reference to `bs` is:

> bs=BYTES
>
> read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time

Comment: 512 Bytes per second would be painfully slow

Comment: I know, that was just the first number that popped into my head while writing that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with other GNU Coreutils utilities, the primary documentation is the `info` page.

From `info coreutils dd invocation` :

```
‘bs=BYTES’
     Set both input and output block sizes to BYTES.  This makes ‘dd’
     read and write BYTES per block, overriding any ‘ibs’ and ‘obs’
     settings.  In addition, if no data-transforming ‘conv’ option is
     specified, input is copied to the output as soon as it’s read, even
     if it is smaller than the block size.
```

There are corresponding parameters for the individual read, write and conversion block sizes:

```
‘ibs=BYTES’
     Set the input block size to BYTES.  This makes ‘dd’ read BYTES per
     block.  The default is 512 bytes.

‘obs=BYTES’
     Set the output block size to BYTES.  This makes ‘dd’ write BYTES
     per block.  The default is 512 bytes.

‘cbs=BYTES’
     Set the conversion block size to BYTES.  When converting
     variable-length records to fixed-length ones (‘conv=block’) or the
     reverse (‘conv=unblock’), use BYTES as the fixed record length.
```